# Error when try to display photos on homepage : "The asset "courses/image1" is not present in the asset pipeline"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am newbie with Rails and trying to display photos to my homepage and here is my code at my home.html.erb

```
<br/>
<div class="row">
<% @courses.each do |course| %>
<div class="col m4">
<div class="card">
<div class="card-image">
 <%= link_to course do %>
    <%= image_tag "courses/#{course.image}" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<div class="card-content">
  <span class="card-title"><%= course.title %></span>
  <% (1..course.star).each do %>
  <1 class="material-icons" green-text>grade</i>
  <% end %>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

I made another page named "course" to upload photo to the homepage.
Then, when I ran the code, it said to me that at the line `<%= image_tag "courses/#{course.image}" %>` there was an error. `The asset "courses/image1" is not present in the asset pipeline.`

Here is what I did.

First, I went to app/assets/images.

Second, I made folder which named "photos".

Third put image to the folder "photos".
And Last I tried the code but there was the error.

Could you please give me some ideas? Thank you very much.

Comment: image extension?

Answer (score 0):

Rails is pretty smart, so when you provide it a path in an `image_tag`, such as `courses/images1`, it prepends this path with `app/assets/images` (by default) such that the full relative path is `app/assets/images/courses/images1`.

So to update your `image_tag` you should firstly pass it your image file type: `.jpg` or `.png` etc. Second update your path to `photos/images.file_type` where `filetype` is your image filetype. If you want to put a `/courses` directory in your `/photos` file, and place `image1.file_type` in there, then your path would be `photos/courses/images.file_type`.